# Javascript smooth resizing on display of extra text

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have some text in my website, but to display it all at once, it would take up too much space. So I have created a simple button, that when clicked, shows all the extra text that is normally hidden using `display: none`. This works perfectly, but isn't currently animated, and doesn't fit the theme of the website too well.

I was wondering if it was possible to animate the (dis)appearance of this extra text, using basic CSS animation functions. This is what I currently have:

**HTML:**

```html
<h3 style="margin-bottom: 0.3em;">some text</h3>
<p>some more text</p>
                        
<span id="more" style="display: none; transition: all .5s linear;">
    <h3 style="margin-bottom: 0.3em;">Some hidden text</h3>
    <p>some more hidden text</p>
</span>

<button id="readMore" onclick="readMore()">Read more</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```js
var active = false;
var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
var button = document.getElementById("readMore");

function readMore()
{
    if(active == false)
    {
        active = true;
        moreText.style.display = "inline";
        button.innerHTML = "Read less";
    }
    else if(active == true)
    {
        active = false;
        moreText.style.display = "none";
        button.innerHTML = "Read more";
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly, except for the `transition: all .5s linear;`, because it is currently not animated. I've also tried to apply this to the most outer div that this code is located in, because that also changes in size, but this also didn't seem to work.

My question is, it it even possible to animate these kinds of changes, and if so, can anybody point me to the right direction of how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

CSS transitions won't work when going from "display: none" to "display: inline". I would recommend utilizing the CSS visibility property. Consider moving your h3 and p tags into a div first.

```js
function readMore()
{
    if(active == false)
    {
        active = true;
        moreText.style.visibility = "visible";
        moreText.style.maxHeight = "600px";
        button.innerHTML = "Read less";
    }
    else if(active == true)
    {
        active = false;
        //moreText.style.display = "none";
        moreText.style.visibility = "hidden";
        moreText.style.maxHeight = "0";
        button.innerHTML = "Read more";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="more" style="visibility: hidden; transition: all .5s linear; max-height:0;">
  <h3 style="margin-bottom: 0.3em;">Some hidden text</h3>
  <p>some more hidden text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try and use CSS classes, which may be simpler.

**HTML:**

```
<body> 
    <h3 >some text</h3>
    <p>some more text</p>
                            
    <span id="more" class='more-container'>
        <h3>Some hidden text</h3>
        <p>some more hidden text</p>
    </span>
    
    <button id="readMore">Read more</button>

</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
const button = document.getElementById("readMore");
const moreText = document.getElementById("more");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (moreText.classList.value.includes("active")){
        moreText.classList.remove("active")
        button.classList.remove("button-active")
    } else {
        moreText.classList.add("active")
        button.classList.add("button-active")
    }
})
```

**Note:**

- I used an event listener here instead of the `onClick` function call, which is just my preference

**CSS:**

```
.more-container {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

button {
  margin-top: -80px;
  position: relative;
}

.button-active {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Display: `block` and `none` can not have a transition because it shows or hides the element in DOM. Either we can use visibility property to smoothly show and hide that section. The same has been suggested in other answers as well.

Or, I would suggest not to use visibility and use `max-height` with the transition as this is a `Read More` thing. So the ideally it should expand to the bottom on "Show More" and collapse on "Show Less". Here is a code snippet imitating the same behaviour:

```
  <body>
    <h3 style="margin-bottom: 0.3em;">some text</h3>
    <p>some more text</p>

    <span
      id="more"
      style="
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-height: 0;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
      "
    >
      <h3 style="margin-bottom: 0.3em;">Some hidden text</h3>
      <p>some more hidden text</p>
    </span>

    <button id="readMore" onclick="readMore()">Read more</button>

    <script>
      var active = false;
      var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
      var button = document.getElementById("readMore");
      moreText.style.overflow = "hidden";

      function readMore() {
        if (active == false) {
          active = true;
          moreText.style.maxHeight = "100px";
          button.innerHTML = "Read less";
        } else if (active == true) {
          active = false;
          moreText.style.maxHeight = 0;
          button.innerHTML = "Read more";
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
```

And the [codesandbox for the same](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-feather-ggx3c).